# Synchronize data in mutiple laptop AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I built an application and I host it in a local server. I would like When multiple users open the app and someone for example modify something, the modification will be applied for all the others automatically without refreshing the page.

I found a solution, that I call the function every 5 seconds for example, but when the number of users increase, it will make the request so slow sometimes. So I think it's not the better solution. Have you please any idea about this issue, what is the best solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/amark/gun.

Comment: Try using something liker firebase realtime db. Its simple enough and would do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), which is an older way of handling this case. This would still have the performance/scalability issues you mentioned but works for simpler cases. More recently the [websockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) exposes an easy way to get bidirectional communication between client and server with less overhead than polling.

A popular library for doing this nowadays is [socket.io](https://socket.io/), which utilizes both long-polling and websockets and lets you easily handle things like disconnections and the like.

Comment: thanks a lot, i would like to know why $timeout slow the request when mutiple users connects ?

Comment: when you poll your application opens a connection, transmits any new data, then closes the connection. This happens even when there is nothing to do. As number of users increases, the time spent opening and closing client connections starts to get expensive.